# Como pegar dados de um COUNT com php e mysql e armazenar em uma lista e acessalas

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, count

Eu estou criando um graficos dos bairros que mais comprar X produtos, entao o que eu pensei, em criar um COUNT(bairro) para contar os bairros que se repetem e dizer quantas vezes se repetem, so que eu queria acessar dados por dados para colocar o nome do bairro e o valor que se repete:

```
include_once '../cadastro/config.php';
?>
<?php
        $quer_cont = "SELECT bairro AS bairros,COUNT(bairro) AS qntvez  FROM cadastro GROUP BY bairro HAVING COUNT(bairro) >= 1 ORDER BY count(bairro) DESC LIMIT 4";
        $result = $conn->prepare($quer_cont);
        $result->execute();

        if(($result) AND ($result->rowCount() != 0)){
         
          while($row_cont = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
            
            echo $row_cont->bairro;
             };
        
      }
```

quando eu conseguisse acessar essas informações queria jogar a variavel nesse grafico:

````
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
       

    
        ["Element", "Density", { role: "style" } ],
        ["<?php echo $bairro?>", 0, "#b87333"],
        ["<?php echo $bairro?>", 10.49, "silver"],
        ["<?php echo $bairro?>", 19.30, "gold"],
        ["Platinum", 21.45, "color: #e5e4e2"]
   
      ]);

      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view.setColumns([0, 1,
                       { calc: "stringify",
                         sourceColumn: 1,
                         type: "string",
                         role: "annotation" },
                       2]);

      var options = {
        title: "Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3",
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
        legend: { position: "none" },
      };
      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
      chart.draw(view, options);
  }
  </script>
<div id="columnchart_values" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div> ```
````

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Depois de alguns dias eu descobrir a solucao, No caso eu queria pegar os bairros que mais se repetiam, fiz um php que contava os bairros e fazia um rank, e eu queria acessalos de alguma forma foi dae que achei a soluacao para acessalos e mostrar no meu Grafico :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Testando dashboard</title>
</head>
<body>
  

<?php
include "../cadastro/config.php";
        $quer_cont1 = "SELECT bairro AS bairros,COUNT(bairro) AS qntvez  FROM cadastro GROUP BY bairro HAVING COUNT(bairro) >= 1 ORDER BY count(bairro) DESC LIMIT 1";
        $result1 = $conn->prepare($quer_cont1);
        $result1->execute();
        $qntvez1 = array();
        $bairro1 = array();

        $i = 0;

        
         
          while($row_cont1 = $result1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
              $qntvez1 = $row_cont1['qntvez'];
              $bairro1 = $row_cont1['bairros'];
        };
        $quer_cont2 = "SELECT bairro AS bairros,COUNT(bairro) AS qntvez  FROM cadastro GROUP BY bairro HAVING COUNT(bairro) >= 1 ORDER BY count(bairro) DESC LIMIT 2";
        $result2 = $conn->prepare($quer_cont2);
        $result2->execute();
        $qntvez2 = array();
        $bairro2 = array();
        while($row_cont2 = $result2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
          $qntvez2 = $row_cont2['qntvez'];
          $bairro2 = $row_cont2['bairros'];
    };
    $quer_cont3 = "SELECT bairro AS bairros,COUNT(bairro) AS qntvez  FROM cadastro GROUP BY bairro HAVING COUNT(bairro) >= 1 ORDER BY count(bairro) DESC LIMIT 3";
        $result3 = $conn->prepare($quer_cont3);
        $result3->execute();
        $qntvez3 = array();
        $bairro3 = array();
        while($row_cont3 = $result3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
          $qntvez3 = $row_cont3['qntvez'];
          $bairro3 = $row_cont3['bairros'];
    };
    $quer_cont4 = "SELECT bairro AS bairros,COUNT(bairro) AS qntvez  FROM cadastro GROUP BY bairro HAVING COUNT(bairro) >= 1 ORDER BY count(bairro) DESC LIMIT 4";
    $result4 = $conn->prepare($quer_cont4);
    $result4->execute();
    $qntvez4 = array();
    $bairro4 = array();
    while($row_cont4 = $result4->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
      $qntvez4 = $row_cont4['qntvez'];
      $bairro4 = $row_cont4['bairros'];
};
        
      
        ?>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js" integrity="sha256-3zlB5s2uwoUzrXK3BT7AX3FyvojsraNFxCc2vC/7pNI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
      var dados = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
       

        ["Element", "Density", { role: "style" } ],
        ['<?php echo $bairro1 ?>', <?php echo $qntvez1 ?>, "#b87333"],
        ["<?php echo $bairro2 ?>", <?php echo $qntvez2 ?>, "silver"],
        ["<?php echo $bairro3 ?>", <?php echo $qntvez3 ?>, "gold"],
        ["<?php echo $bairro4 ?>", <?php echo $qntvez4 ?>, "color: #e5e4e2"]
   
   
      ]);

      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(dados);
      view.setColumns([0, 1,
                       { calc: "stringify",
                         sourceColumn: 1,
                         type: "string",
                         role: "annotation" },
                       ]);

      var options = {
        title:  "Bairros que mais compram",
        width: 540,
        height: 400,
        bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
        legend: { position: "none" },
      };
      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
      chart.draw(view, options);
      
  }
```